# jqgrid grid columns to subgrid

Tags: ajax, jqgrid

I have the following code which works fine and creates the grid with 4 columns:

```
 $("#"+GRID).jqGrid({
            url:'ajax.htm',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            jsonReader: { repeatitems : false, cell:"", id: "id", userdata: "jsonModel", root: "rows" },
            postData: {
                ajaxRequest: document.helper.getPageName(),
                screenMode: 'getList'
            },
            colNames:[
                'id'
                'listname',
                'customer'.
                'employee'.
                'sum'
            ],
            colModel:[        
                {name:'id', index:'id', editable:false, hidden: true},
                {name:'listname', index:'id', editable:false, hidden: true},
                {name:'customer', index:'customerColumn', editable:false, sortable:true},
                {name:'employee', index:'employeeColumn', editable:false, sortable:true},
                {name:'sum', index:'sum', editable:false, sortable:true}
            ],
            autowidth:true,
            shrinkToFit:true,
            rownumbers:true,
            pager:$('#'+GRID_PAGER),
            sortname: 'listname',
            sortorder: "desc",
            loadonce: true,
            rowNum:30,
            rowList:[10, 30, 50],
            viewrecords:true,
            gridComplete:function () {
                var data = $("#"+GRID).getGridParam('userData');

        })
```

This code have no subgrids.

Is it posible to edit this, so the grid will have only columns `'id'` and `'listname'`, and on subgrid are `'customer','employee','sum'`.

Does subgrid needs another ajax call?

I read that the following lines should be added

subGrid: true,
subGridRowExpanded: function (subGridId, rowId) {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html see grid as subgrid demo, it is in the advanced tab.